# Change default structure of JSON returned from Java controller

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a controller which returns a list of objects as a `ResponseEntity`, `JSON` being returned is of following format:

```
[
  {
    “name”:”a”,
    “classes”:
    [
        “1”,”2”,”3”
    ]
  }]
```

I want to restructure it in following format:

```
[{“a”:[“1”,”2”,”3”]}]
```

I have a hunch that I have to make my own `JSON Object` and return it in some `@JsonValue` annotated method, but I do not want to do it.

Is there another way?

Comment: Adding a comment on why you downvoted would be nice, I need help because I am new in Java that's why I asked.

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: `{“a”:[“1”,”2”,”3”], “b”:[“1”,”2”,”3”]}` by using `ResponseEntity` of `List<Map<String, List<String>>` you can change the generated response from controller in custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Convert object to list of `Map`-s in a right structure.
2. Write custom serialiser.

Custom serialiser should be easy in this case:

```
class PojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Pojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Pojo value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField(value.getName(), value.getClasses());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And simple usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, Arrays.asList(new Pojo(), new Pojo()));
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = PojoSerializer.class)
class Pojo {
    private String name = "a";
    private List<String> classes = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    // getters, setters
}
```

prints:

```
[ {
  "a" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}, {
  "a" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
} ]
```